# VSCode intellisense default imports not working

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I have following code in my library called @qual/utilities.

**math.js**

```
export default sum(a, b) { return a + b });
```

**index.js**

```
export sum from './math'; // however vscode complains on this line - Declaration or statement expected.ts(1128)
```

**Babelrc** looks like

```
{
  "plugins": [    
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from",
```

While consuming this library -

`import { sum } from '@qual/utilities'; // also here I do not get any intellisense`

How can I make I make VSCode work with this imports.

I tried setting eslint rules to disable warnings but that didn't work

```
"comma-dangle": ["error", {
   "arrays": "never",
   "objects": "never",
   "imports": "never",
   "exports": "never",
   "functions": "never"
}]
```